# Executing a function on catcing input from Property Binding in Angular

Tags: angular, property-binding

```
@Input() UpItem: Item ;
```

On catching something in UpItem I want to execute a function when some property is passed from parent to child.

Comment: explore `ngOnChanges` life cycle hook

Answer (score 0):

Using a getter/setter is probably the best way

```ts
private _upItem:Item
@Input() set UpItem(value:Item) {
  this._upItem = value;
  this.doSomething();
}
get UpItem():Item {
  return this._upItem;
}
```

`ngOnInit` might be more convenient if you want to call the same code when one or more of several different inputs change

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on "some scenarios"?

Comment: I didn't have much hands on . But i write observable ,function ,and a console line but only observable works

Comment: If something doesn't work, please edit your question and add the code that doesn't work (and the expected behavior), then post a comment so I'll get a notification. Then I can have a look.